# Created a namespace extension rooted at a file system folder using EZnamespaceextension

Tags: c#

I have created a namespace extension rooted at a file system folder using EZnamespaceextension for a virtual drive to show my custom view but when i register it, it does not show anything. But if I register it for a normal drive it shows its custom view and working perfectly . I am doing it for my personal interest and as a testing basis.

Could anyone suggest me why it is not showing the custom view to the specific virtual drive?

Comment: Could you rewrite your question, cause i absolutely don't understand what you could maybe mean.

Comment: what do you mean register it as normal drive?
it's all about the properties in your root folder, which then you use the custom EXE EZNamespace provides to register your namespace in the registry.
eventually, it's translated into attributes flags, which properties did you put?